# How to set multiple buttons in Relative Layout in multiple lines

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

I had created a layout programatically and created multiple buttons in it dynamically. I want when screen ends the remaining buttons show below of above buttons. Please do me the favour.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use layout params.

Comment: Use flow layout https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: can you explain some thing more about how you did and what is the result your are getting etc

Comment: In my app, five to six buttons came in a row and rest of buttons are not showing. I have a Listview containing multiple buttons in particular row. I had created a parent Layout, and another inner layout contain all the buttons and finally I add inner layout into parent layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating the root layout dynamically you have to set root layout's layoutParams dynamically.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
             ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

ll.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and add the views to this layout

```
Button btn=new Button(this);
ll.addView(btn, layoutParams);
```

didn't tested it please try this code

### Update

```
 RelativeLayout lLRoot = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    lLRoot.addView(ll);

    Button btn=new Button(this);
    btn.setText("hai");
    ll.addView(btn);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but I have another layout containing all the buttons and then that layout add into root layout. Then how I can proceed.

Comment: Get the root layout by findViewById() and add it in the same way like before

     lLRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
     lLRoot.addView(ll, layoutParams);

Comment: I want to create 8-10 buttons in one single row and when screen ends then it will goes down, not in another row but in same row.

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

add this layout param to all your buttons if you are adding it to a linear layout